# Issue with running shell command in python 3 (Windows 11)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I wanted to run a command from Python 3 (3.8.10 to be exact). Here is what I tried:

```py
import os
os.system("ls")
```

Output:

```
'DOSKEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I was pretty frustrated, but I tried `echo` since that was a basic command:

```
import os
os.system("echo hi!")
```

Output:

```
'DOSKEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

hi!
```

So that worked. I'm now stumped. Why did `echo` work and not `ls`? And why does it say that DOSKEY is not an internal or external command and how do I fix it.

Edit:
I now tried the `subprocess` method:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["echo", "hi"]) # If I understand correctly, the arguments have to be separated by array elements like so
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\lucas\.spyder-py3\automated_run.py:8
    subprocess.run(["echo","hi"])

  File subprocess.py:493 in run

  File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py:109 in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File subprocess.py:858 in __init__

  File subprocess.py:1311 in _execute_child

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ls` is a linux/unix command. Windows (CMD.exe) uses `dir`. It's weird with doskey here but it seems that the system call is trying to use doskey and can't find it. Possibly you just need to fiddle with PATH (see similar problem: https://superuser.com/questions/988311/doskey-is-not-recognized-when-using-cmder)

Comment: `dir` seems to work. It's weird that `ls` works in powershell?

Comment: powershell has a built-in alias so that `ls` works - probably both dir and ls are mapped to `Get-ChildItem()` (I'm guessing a bit though)

Comment: check, if you're able to execute doskey from a command prompt, e.g. `doskey /?`

Comment: Nope. But, when the command worked, there were no DOSKEY complaints.